# display a shop's marker which is already on google

Tags: javascript, google-maps

okay, there is a shop on the map. and I am trying to display that shop's marker on my map. I am a bit confused about passing the marker's location.

this is the location that I got from marker on google map.

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Starbucks/@34.6748217,135.4293592,12z/data=!3m1!5s0x6000e693a22a809f:0xa230d50a2bd936b4!4m8!1m2!2m1!1sstarbucks!3m4!1s0x0:0xe83a23a6e585f341!8m2!3d34.7037647!4d135.499835

and at the line here: `/Starbucks/@34.6748217,135.4293592` I took the geo and put it my location. But I am not sure is it the right way to do it? Because I don't want to create new marker. I want to put a marker which is  ALREADY on google map.

this is simple map:

```
  function initMap() {
    var starbucks = {lat: 34.6748217, lng: 135.4293592};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: starbucks
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: starbucks,
      map: map,
      // title: 'starbucks'
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will just put a marker on your map. If that's all you need, you might consider using the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) instead which can generate a link directly to the place you mentioned by using its place ID and can be easily embedded on any webpage.

```html
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=place_id:ChIJYaAqopPmAGARQfOF5aYjOug&key=AIzaSyA-n9P6rX_0r8ySKnttYTVLAdh3SMcJaKE" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

You need to generate and use your own API key (replace the one in the above code) and enable the Maps Embed API in the [console](https://console.developers.google.com).